# Python Plugin for Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I installed PythonScript_1.0.8.0 for notepad++, saved my first script as Test.py
and filled it as follows:

```
     Editor.selectAll() 
     Editor.paste() 
     notepad.runPluginCommand('NPPExport', 'Copy RTF to clipboard')
```

However when running, I got the following error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts\Test.py",
>   line 1, in
>
> Editor.selectAll()
>
> TypeError: unbound method Boost.Python.function object must be called
>   with Editor instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Any Help?

Comment: The exception seems to be very clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `editor` instead of `Editor`. `Editor` is the class and `editor` is the instance. Example:

```
editor.selectAll()
```

Comment: Thanks rnevius. That is it. Sorry I am new to Python. I will accept the solution shortly